# javascript regex: `foo` -> **foo**?

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I hack Markdown engine for my own website.

Now, I'm trying to convert any string that is wrapped with single `

```
`foo`
```

to

```
 **foo**
```

using `regex` and so far, all I can think of is

```
    var data = data0.replace(/`.*`/g, '...');
```

and obviously, this does not work for what I intend.

and Markdown also has

````
```  ```
````

format, and I want this untouched- exclude from regex match.

Can you advise what the regex would be?

Thank you.

Comment: What should happen to ``?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is my attempt at a simple, clean regex:

**Regex string**

```
`\b(.*?)\b`(?!`)
```

**Replace string**

```
**$1**
```

**Online Demonstration**

[**Regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/sZ7eR0)

Comment: That precludes many valid matches. For example, it requires a backtick-enclosed string to always start and end with an ASCII letter/digit/underscore.

Comment: Thank you. I like the simplicity, your answer is checked.

Comment: Ok, could you tell me what's wrong with this solution? Tim. Also I found the whole answer here does not work if `foo` is `SPACEfoo` or `fooSPACE` or `SPECIALCHARACTORfoo` etc.

Comment: Tim's solution is more complete than mine in that it will match ``-foo-`` or ``.foo.``, it just depends what you're going to put inside the ` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions, we need to use a little trick:

```
result = subject.replace(/(^|[^`])`([^`]*)`(?!`)/g, '$1**$2**');
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/iQ6zG5).

**Explanation:**

```
(^|[^`]) # Match the start of the string or any non-` character.
`        # Match `
([^`]*)  # Match any number of non-` characters
`        # Match `
(?!`)    # Assert that no ` follows
```

Comment: Thanks, but `$1**$2""` is obviously typo.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that:

```
var data = data0.replace(/(^|[^`].|.[^`])`([^`]+)`(?!``)/g, '$1**$2**');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5E7q/3/)

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dF6lK7)

Since JS doesn't have negative lookbehind, you have to resort to something like `(^|[^].|.[^])` to prevent matching ``` `` ``` before the third `` ` ``.

``` (?!``) ``` then prevents matching of ``` `` ``` after the 4th `` ` ``.

Comment: This changes `"foo |bar|"` (pipes instead of backticks for formatting reasons) to `"fo**bar**"`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I was fixing that... :x

Comment: Your regex leaves `` unchanged. I don't think that's desired.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I would rather think that `` should be left alone. Plus mine changes `"||foo|"` to `"|**foo**"` which yours doesn't (using pipes instead of backticks for formatting reasons).

Comment: Fair point. I guess it comes down to what the OP will specify as correct behavior for these "pathological" cases.